# How do I convert a time to total milliseconds in R?

Tags: r, time, milliseconds

I would like to convert a time to total milliseconds in R.

Example

13:00 -> 46800000

Comment: As this can't be rocket science, it does not hurt to show some self effort.

Answer (score 4):

For the fun of it:

```
f <- function(v) sapply(strsplit(v, ":", T), function(x) sum(as.numeric(x) * c(60*60, 60, 1)[seq(x)]*1000))
f(c("13:00", "13:00:00", "14:00:00.001"))       
# [1] 46800000 46800000 50400001
```

Comment: Thanks lukeA I am new to R, just started so this will help.

Comment: @RoniHoffman Please avoid "thanks" comment. Accept the answer instead.